# Long answers editing goes weird on Vivaldi

Tags: bug, browser-support

Writing or editing long answers with code segments goes weird, and the editing cursor always resets to a specific position... long lines of code breaks the format.

E.g my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719172/larvel-5-3-update-record-only-update-changed-record-and-leave-the-unchanged-rec/42719713#42719713). I had to download Firefox to fix the formatting.

Vivaldi version: 1.7.735.46 (Stable channel) (64-bit) 
OS: Arch Linux

Can anyone confirm?

Note: I am not sure whose responsibility it is to fix this.

---

## Edit 1

I have tried google chrome as they share rendering engine, but it works flawlessly in chrome.

Comment: Vivaldi is not on the [list of supported browsers,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) so they may not be going to fix this.

Comment: Aha. Thanks for the info.. I think I will have another one for SO.

Comment: You sure this is specific to Vivaldi and doesn't happen on Chropera or Chrome?

Comment: Re: "...had to download Firefox to fix...". Isn't using a text editor an option (using copy-paste to transfer the text)? Like [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs)?